# C++ avoiding dynamic dispatch in derived classes with using keyword

Tags: c++, virtual-functions, dynamic-dispatch

In the following example, will I be using dynamic dispatch to call the virtual functions?

```
struct Base{
    virtual double fn(){return 3.2;}
};
struct Deri1 : public Base{
    using Base::fn;
}
struct Deri2 : public Base{
    virtual double fn(){return 4.6;}
}
```

The classes I'm implementing contain much more information, but there is some that I want to keep default for some derived classes but override in others, the fn() in above code is an example of this. Basically, I'm just using the base class to avoid rewritting fn() every time it's not overridden. Is this the right way?

Thanks!

Comment: `Deri2` does not inherit from `Base`. Is that intentional?

Comment: Oops! Sorry! I've corrected it now.

Comment: You don't even need to put a using directive in this case. Only if you overload the function, in addition to not wanting to override it.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm rather trying to avoid dynamic dispatch, i.e. use of vtables to determine the virtual function. Also, in the extension, there is some overloading going on.

Comment: If you don't want dynamic dispatch, just don't make the functions `virtual`.

Comment: @KerrekSB But then I won't be able to override them, right...?

Comment: @KarrekSB OK I think I understand now. I can simply overload the function 'fn()' in 'Deri2' and thereby avoid the 'virtual' keyword. Why use 'virtual' ever, in that case?? Unless it's an pure virtual function, it doesn't seem to make any sense. One only loses efficiency due to vtable lookups.

Comment: If you don't use virtual functions, you should not use public inheritance either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can avoid dynamic dispatch by avoiding the 'virtual' keyword in the definition of the function, **so long as one doesn't uses pointers**, as explained in this [link](http://www.opengurukul.com/vlc/mod/page/view.php?id=3680).

This creates some complications with generic methods and polymorphism. If one is using dynamic polymorphism, one would pass a pointer to the base class to a method, in which case the 'virtual' keyword is necessary for the pointer to determine which method to use. One can define a static polymorphic method using templates, as explained in the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19109620/c-static-rather-than-dynamic-polymorphism).